# Is it possible to somehow undo the results of the mv command?

Tags: data-recovery, data-loss

Here's the problem. I had a bunch of files in a directory. Then I created another directory in that directory. Then I cobbled together this command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} ./1 \;
```

This command was supposed to take all the files in the directory and move them to that newly-created directory, but instead of providing the name of the directory, I screwed up and typed **1**, as you can see from the code snippet. So, I ended up having just one text file named **1** that now contains the stuff from one of the disappeared files and that's all.

Is there any chance I could recover the lost files (or possibly the actual data from the files--they were all text files) or are they pretty much permanently gone?

---

Before:

```
misha@hp-laptop:~/Documents/prgmg/work$ ls
add.s  bubble.s  cpuid.s  div.s    hello.s  mult.s       sum.s   test.s
a.out  c         demo.s   gas.txt  max.s    print_arr.s  test.c
misha@hp-laptop:~/Documents/prgmg/work$ mkdir asm
```

After:

```
misha@hp-laptop:~/Documents/prgmg/work$ ls
1  asm  c
```

So, as you can see, I wanted to put all assembly language files into the `asm` directory. And as things stand now, `1` is a text file and it contains the stuff from `gas.txt`.

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Magic_Rescue

Comment: I have mistyped directory names many times and moved or copied a file into a filename instead of directory.  To avoid this I have begun to always place a trailing slash "/" so that I would get an error that the directory doesn't exist if I mistype the directory name.  Or at worst, it will go into a wrong directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lost ALL but the last file offered up by `find`, it is now called `./1`. Note that `find` finds files in its own order, so "last" doesn't mean what you think. By inserting an `echo` in front of the `mv`, we see:

```
Script started on Thu 14 Jul 2016 07:02:01 PM EDT
+w3@aardvark:~(0)$ mkdir tmp/answer
+w3@aardvark:~(0)$ cd !$
cd tmp/answer
+w3@aardvark:~/tmp/answer(0)$ for i in a b c d; do
> mkdir $i
> done
+w3@aardvark:~/tmp/answer(0)$ for i in a/1 b/2 c/3 d/4 a/0 ; do
> touch $i
> done
+w3@aardvark:~/tmp/answer(0)$ touch 9 8 7 6
+w3@aardvark:~/tmp/answer(0)$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo mv {} ./1 \;
mv ./8 ./1
mv ./6 ./1
mv ./9 ./1
mv ./7 ./1
+w3@aardvark:~/tmp/answer(0)$ exit

Script done on Thu 14 Jul 2016 07:05:21 PM EDT
```